# Is it possible to do a nested query builder in AdonisJs with Lucid?

Tags: node.js, relationships, adonis.js

I want to know if it is possible to do a nested ".scope" query with Lucid in AdonisJs? I want to get all Orders that don't have the 'd' status in OrderItems for a given Office (Laravel uses whereHas('orders.items') for this).

An example:

```
const office = yield Office
  .query()
  .with('orders.items')
  .where('id', officeId)
  .scope('orders.items', (builder) => {
    builder.whereNot('status','d')
  })
  .first()
```

But this only filters out all OrderItems that have the 'd' status, so I still get a list that contains Orders with empty Item arrays:

```
office: {
  orders: [{
    items: [{
      status: 'p'
    }, {
      status: 'c'
    }]
  },{
    items: []
  },{
    items: []
  }]]
}
```

I want to get this result:

```
office: {
  orders: [{
    items: [{
      status: 'p'
    }, {
      status: 'c'
    }]
  }]]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do nested queries but they do not filter the top level rows. In short `whereHas` is not supported in Lucid.

The return result is a lodash collection, so you can filter the result by removing the empty arrays. I would suggest to create an issue for same on Github.

### Update

The support for same has been added. Checkout this thread https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-lucid/issues/92